# Session State FIPS Validation Error in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, encryption, fips, tls1.2

I am attempting to enable TLS 1.2 on our Windows 2008 R2 server for PCI compliance, and have managed to get it working by following [this obscure blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2011/10/07/secure-channel-compatibility-support-with-ssl-and-tls.aspx) which requires turning on FIPS validation. Finally, after weeks of looking for a solution, click-once, .NET remoting, and MS Web Deploy are communicating over TLS 1.2.

However, I also have web applications on the machine that quit functioning when I enabled FIPS validation with the following error:

> **This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.**
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**
>
> [InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.]
>      System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged..ctor() +10489630
>      System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.ConfigureEncryptionObject() +439
>      System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EnsureConfig() +152
>      System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.HashData(Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length) +48
>      System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.HashAndBase64EncodeString(String s) +136
>      System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.OneTimeInit() +763
>      System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.Initialize(String name, NameValueCollection config) +223
>      System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.Initialize(String name, NameValueCollection config, IPartitionResolver partitionResolver) +43
>      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.InitModuleFromConfig(HttpApplication app, SessionStateSection config) +11279756
>      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +155
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +480
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +350
>      System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +382
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11421094
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +88
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4405316
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5491

I am using the ASP.NET state service with all 3 of the applications and they are getting this stack trace.

I have searched around for solutions and they all basically say to switch the algorithm to one that is FIPS compliant.

- [Problem with FIPS Validated Cryptographic Algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104331/problem-with-fips-validated-cryptographic-algorithms)
- [ASPX pages fail due to FIPS 140 security policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355654/aspx-pages-fail-due-to-fips-140-security-policy)

But since this is being thrown by ASP.NET itself what is the solution? I am using .NET 3.5, would upgrading to a newer framework solve the issue? Or is there a simpler fix, such as a configuration setting?

> NOTE: I also attempted to use in-process session state which bypasses this error and then I am getting the same error with cookie encryption (which is apparently also using `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged`). I tried setting the machine key to the one in the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (for a test), and also combined it with AES as the decryption and validation settings, but it didn't have any effect on the error message.

Comment: This article "IS 7.5: How to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2" (http://www.basics.net/2015/10/06/iis-7-5-how-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/) may help. TLS may need to be enabled by changing the registry. My Windows 7 system had it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The following changes worked in my situation...

1. Enable TLS protocols in Windows registry. See [IIS 7.5: How to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2](http://www.basics.net/2015/10/06/iis-7-5-how-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/)
2. In the application code, add the following line of code when the application starts (e.g., `Application_Start` for a `System.Web.Http.Application`)

   `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`